# This class of the AppComponent is deprecated, please use "sap.fe.core.AppComponent" instead

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Did anyone of you come across this error:
"This class of the AppComponent is deprecated, please use "sap.fe.core.AppComponent" instead"

I am trying to create a Fiori application with the following:

Index.html file:

```html
 <script>
  window["sap-ushell-config"] = {
   defaultRenderer: "fiori2",
   applications: {
    "browse-books": {
     title: "Browse PFG requests",
     description: "... testing FE v42",
     additionalInformation: "SAPUI5.Component=pfgPortal",
     applicationType : "URL",
     url: "/pfgAdmin/webapp",
     navigationMode: "embedded"
    }   
   }
  };
 </script>
```

Component.js code:

```js
sap.ui.define(["sap/fe/AppComponent"], ac => ac.extend("pfgPortal.Component", {
    metadata:{ manifest:'json' }
}))
```

Can anyone help me with, where an I possibly going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried following the recommendation of the error message?

Comment: Hi Marc, As I put in the code. I am already using the recommended version.

Comment: Are you using this then in your Component.js? `sap.ui.define(["sap/fe/core/AppComponent"]`